# How to draw features with openlayers?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers-2

I have a `DrawFeature` tool.

```js
create= new OpenLayers.Control.DrawFeature(myVecLayer,
OpenLayers.Handler.Polygon);
app.mapPanel.map.addControl(create);
```

I have a store.

```js
st = new GeoExt.data.FeatureStore({
    layer: myVecLayer,
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'mydata', type: 'String'},
    ],
     proxy: new GeoExt.data.ProtocolProxy({
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            version: "1.0.0",
            srsName:"EPSG:900913",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
            featureType: "filedata_temp",
            featureNS: "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite",
            filter:Ffilter
        })
    }),
    autoLoad: true
});
```

I start drawing

```js
for(var i=0;i<create_cont.length;i++){
   create_cont[1].activate();
}
```

After I put attributes to feature and save result

```js
Openlayers.Strategy.Save().save()
```

But it's not saved.

POST

```xml
<wfs:Transaction xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" service="WFS" version="1.1.0"  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <wfs:Insert>
  <feature:filedata_temp xmlns:feature="http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite">
   <feature:the_geom>
    <gml:Polygon xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" srsName="EPSG:900913">
     <gml:exterior>
      <gml:LinearRing>
       <gml:posList>6756846.305626001 7731074.3336396 6756578.776027001 7730338.6272425 6757696.667564999 7730118.8707862 6758441.928590998 7730978.7873543 6756846.305626001 7731074.3336396</gml:posList>
      </gml:LinearRing>
     </gml:exterior>
    </gml:Polygon>
   </feature:the_geom>
   <feature:id>10</feature:id>
    <feature:mydata>10</feature:mydata>
  </feature:filedata_temp>
 </wfs:Insert>
</wfs:Transaction>
```

ANSWER

```xml
<ows:ExceptionReport version="1.0.0" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows http://localhost:8080/geoserver/schemas/ows/1.0.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows">
 <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue">
  <ows:ExceptionText>Error performing insert: Error inserting features</ows:ExceptionText>
 </ows:Exception>
</ows:ExceptionReport>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It was a PostgresSql bug. I have a two tables whis triggers. If i insert data in first table trigger insert data in second too. But if trigger do this second table's trigger insert data in first table etc. So all what i write in code works fine.

Comment: If that is the solution to this problem could you post it as an answer, see http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/848/increasing-amount-of-questions-left-unanswered-but-in-fact-have-an-answer-inside?cb=1